# Div with fixed position is always stacked on a second div

Tags: html, css, razor

In my `Index.cshtml` (ASP.Net Core MVC) I have the following code:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="text_center">


    <div id="header_parent">
            RESUME INFORMATION
    </div>

    <div class="container containerClass">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-6 green-box">
                <div class="personal">

                    <fieldset>
                        <legend class="personal-information">Personal Information</legend>

                        <div class="personal-name">Name: Daniel Kamel</div>
                        <div class="personal-email">Email: kameldaniel@hotmail.com</div>
                        <div class="personal-address">address: Zouk Mickael</div>

                    </fieldset>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6 red-box">
                <div class="education">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend class="education-education">Education</legend>

                        <label class="education-college">ESIB from 2015 to 2020</label>
                    </fieldset>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

My `site.css` file contains the following snippet:

```
#header_parent {
    position: fixed;
    background-color:aqua;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    height:50px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.containerClass{
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.green-box{
    background-color: green;
}

.red-box{
    background-color: red;
}

.personal-information {
    font-size:35px;
    color:blue;
}

.education-education{
    font-size:35px;
    color:blue;
}

.personal-name{
    font-size: 20px;
}

.personal-email {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.personal-address {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.education-college {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

This is a screenshot of the result:
[image]

The div with `id="header_parent"` is stacked behind the div under it whose class is `class="container containerClass"` and I know that because if I inspect my code on the browser I can see it:

[image]
However if I remove `position:fixed` from my css file the `header_parent` `div` appears at the top of my page which is how I want it to appear however I also want it to have its position fixed, can anyone explain to me why is it producing the above result when I add `position:fixed` in the css file and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `top: 0;` to the css of `#header_parent`. I also added `width: 100%` to the code below as well to make it span the whole width.

```css
#header_parent {
   position: fixed;
    background-color:aqua;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    height:50px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.containerClass{
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.green-box{
    background-color: green;
}

.red-box{
    background-color: red;
}

.personal-information {
    font-size:35px;
    color:blue;
}

.education-education{
    font-size:35px;
    color:blue;
}

.personal-name{
    font-size: 20px;
}

.personal-email {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.personal-address {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.education-college {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text_center">


    <div id="header_parent">
            RESUME INFORMATION
    </div>

    <div class="container containerClass">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-6 green-box">
                <div class="personal">

                    <fieldset>
                        <legend class="personal-information">Personal Information</legend>

                        <div class="personal-name">Name: Daniel Kamel</div>
                        <div class="personal-email">Email: kameldaniel@hotmail.com</div>
                        <div class="personal-address">address: Zouk Mickael</div>

                    </fieldset>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6 red-box">
                <div class="education">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend class="education-education">Education</legend>

                        <label class="education-college">ESIB from 2015 to 2020</label>
                    </fieldset>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: it does work, however when i scroll down and the ```header_parent``` div reaches the ```containerClass``` div it disappears behind it, do you have an idea about how to make it so that it always appears above any other div (or any other html element)?

Comment: @DanielK add a z-index to `#header_parent` So try something like `z-index: 10;` and see if it works